# How can i perform dependent select in easy admin 4 Symfony

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have Category and Subcategory entities. Now on the product creation page, I  need to select category and subcategory. When I select a category then I want to show the subcategories which belong to the selected category. How can I do that in easy admin?

My code in CrudController

```
        yield AssociationField::new('category')
            ->setColumns(4);
        yield AssociationField::new('subcategory')
            ->autocomplete()
```

Comment: Make a custom FormField so that you can use multiple form type, then use something similar to this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms to make your form dynamic